# can we set Mail forward to outlook ID from Mail in database?

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I have a mail in database (not a mail template ) .

I got a requirement as " I Need to forward all the incoming mails to outlook ID from Mail In database " & my user did not want me to create a agent or code for this.

he requested me to achive this from admin side, Is there any possibility to do this?

Description: whenever new mail arrives to mail in database it needs to be forwarded to outlook ID

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is the mail-in db needed for something? You could just create a person record and set a forwarding address there.

Comment: yes Mail in database is a workflow application and it is required. how can i create PD with same name as mail in document? i thought of doing this but PD will become duplicate right?

Comment: right you can't have both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a rule in the database that does the forwarding. Be aware, that this might 
 routing loops, so exclude the forward recipient address from the forwarded mails.
If the database is not based on a mail template, then create the rule on the server or add the design elements needed for rules (forms rule and calendarprofile, folder $Rules, and needed libraries)

If you do not need any mail in the mailbox at all, then do what Panu mentioned in his comment: create a person document for the address (remove the mailin document) and enter a forwarding address there. Attention: you have to have unique addresses, so if you need the mails there, then don't do this...

Another possibility would be to assign the address that is used by the users to a group and change the "real" address of the mailin database to something else and add it as member of the group as well as the external recipient.

If you forward the mail outside of your network, then you most probably will have to configure any appliance between your server and the internet (e.g. a Clearswift, Ironport, etc.) to allow these mails, as for these devices the mail looks like coming from an external sender, sent to an external sender, but coming from an internal host, what makes it think this is a missrouted message or a relay attempt.

And you probably have to change the server configuration document of the server, that sends the smtp message to create a valid return path as shown [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_SPECIFYING_THE_REVERSE_PATH_SETTING_IN_THE_CONFIGURATION_SETTINGS_DOCUMENT_STEPS.html)

Comment: Rule on db- can t create rule as this is not using mail template.
Rule on server - there is not relavent option on server rules.
Creating new PD - can do this since we need those mail inside DB.
Creating new group - i could try this, working on get approval.

Thank u very much Torsten!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You explained that you need two copies of these emails. You need one copy in Outlook and another copy in the workflow application mail-in db.

Easies way without programming seems to be to create a new mailing group, with the old name and email of the mail-in-db, that holds two group members: the new name of a mail-in-db for your application AND the outlook email address.